# MS Excel 2013 - Power Query - [Data.Source Error] Something when wrong when executing the script: Out of stack space

Tags: excel, ms-office, powerquery

When I am trying to update data from [this website](http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/agricultural/grain-and-oilseed/soybean-oil_quotes_settlements_futures.html) by Power Query, I got the message "[Data.Source Error] Something when wrong when executing the script: Out of stack space".

Comment: It may sound silly, but have you tried re-starting your computer? sometimes it's because the Excel runs out of memory.

Comment: I have met this problem several times, so I think restarting may not solve this one.

Comment: Stack (as in stack overflow) is usually a problem of memory, that's why I suggested it. Have a look at your code, maybe it's recursive without a stopping point?

Comment: I just used the import function of power query.